# passing array to gui in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to pass an array to a gui and display each element of that array on axes...the elements are the filenames of images...I have written a piece of code...this is my xyz.m file from which i want to pass an array "result" to a gui result_image.m

```
result_image(result);
```

In opening_fn of the gui i wrote...

```
result = varargin{1};
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
%axes(handles.axes1);
%imshow(im2fn);
for jj = 1:length(result)
axes(handles.axesjj);
imshow(result(jj));
```

I am getting an error as str2func
Invalid function name ''
I dunno what is '' here and also iam getting the error on line result_image(result);
Please Help me!

Comment: I dunno y is it downvoted,i dunno much in matlab so please justify the reason...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-19YHX/?solution=1-19YHX) it will tell you in detail how to add input arguments to your UI. In fact it's a little more complicated than simply adding a `varargin` to your `OpeningFcn` arguments.  The reason is that you have to edit the bit of code that begins with the words `DO NOT EDIT` :-)

You must add some bit of code that allows it to determine that it shouldn't run the code `gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});`. Normally, this bit of code allows external access to the functions (i.e. UI calbacks) in your file, but because it's inside the `if` statement `if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})`, when you pass an argument to your UI that is a string, it thinks you're trying to get a handle to one of the functions in the file and calls `str2func` on the empty string you passed it (which is in `varargin{1}`).

So that's why it doesn't work. You could probably fix this simply by using `varargin{2}` as your input argument instead and opening your UI with `result_image([], result)`, so that `ischar(varargin{1})` is false. To make it a bit more robust, you should probably change

```
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
```

to

```
if nargin > 0 && nargin < 2 && ischar(varargin{1})
```

Note that the fact that you have passed it an empty string in the first place is probably indicative of a bug in your code that opens the UI (i.e., whatever generates `result`).